# How do I change the scrollbar's height on this site?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't set the scrollbar's height on [this site](http://www.demo.creamama.fr/plugin-scrollbar/). Its default height is the window screen's height. How do I change the height?

【I repeat the details，the link  http://taxi.bodait.com/scrollbar2.html  has the problem,how i do to change the height,everyone look look,thanks】

Comment: @elclanrs http://translate.google.com/. Actually pretty smart to leave the original for others to translate.

Comment: This is just the Chinese translation, maybe there are Chinese people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Tiny Scrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) plugin may be what you're searching for.
It allows you to customize the scroll bars of anything.

Comment: I repeat the details，the link http://taxi.bodait.com/scrollbar2.html has the problem,how  i do to change the height,everyone look look,thanks

Comment: Refer this link to change height and mousewheel and all..http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/vertical-scrollbar-using-jquery-ui-slider/